transition vuejs Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
I'm learning about transitions in vuejs. I'm creating a transition in vuejs and get the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" but if I comment out the code, it works normally.I still haven't found the cause. Please help me
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Transition</div>
    <button @click="toggleShow">Show</button>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="show" class="card"></div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Transition",
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow() {
      console.log("Button clicked, current show value:", this.show);
      this.show = !this.show;
      console.log("New show value:", this.show);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.fade-leave {

}
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>



The main issue with your code is you cannot name the component as "Transition", change your component name to other words(e.g. TransitionSample) should solve the issue.
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Transition</div>
    <button @click="toggleShow">Show</button>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="show" class="card"></div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TransitionSample',
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow() {
      console.log('Button clicked, current show value:', this.show);
      this.show = !this.show;
      console.log('New show value:', this.show);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.fade-leave {
}
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>

Transition is a reserved keyword in Vue.js. Vue.js has a built-in component called Transition that is used for applying transition effects to elements or components. When you name your custom component Transition, it conflicts with the built-in Transition component, leading to unexpected behavior and causing an infinite recursive rendering loop. This results in the RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Yes, well spotted! I'm not sure if it conflicts with the built-in component, but it definitely calls itself infinitely because the naming is causing a loop.

Yes, you are right. I just want to emphasize that you cannot name a component with the same name as a built-in component, as it will result in a recursive call stack.
